# Ignore first colunm when importing csv into sql

Tags: mysql, import-from-csv

I have a csv file with 3 columns I want to import into MySQL with Load data infile. The columns are date, item, and qty. I need all three for one table they are going in but only item and qty for the second table. How can I perform this? Would it be the same as Ignore Row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Import / Export wizard, when you get to Select Source Tables and Views click on the button "Edit Mappings" on the bottom left of the screen. That opens column mappings screen; on the destination column select Ignore to remove the column you don't want to import.

https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/importing-a-csv-file-into-your-database-with-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

Comment: No I am doing this through a php script so it has to be a sql query.

Comment: Ahh sorry I see, maybe something on this page will guide you? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns